# Joomla form action, removes "?option=com_helloworld"

Tags: forms, joomla, action

I have a simple form with drop-down choices. I created the simplest "Hello world joomla component...

When a user choose something from the drop-down, the "form action", should redirect to ...for example

`index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=list?Power=3.00&Poles=6`

Unfortunately I got only:

`index.php?Power=3.00&Poles=6`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your url, you have two ?-marks. It should read:

```
index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=list&Power=3.00&Poles=6
```